# Wordpress custom query orderby slug genre and change it with option

Tags: php, wordpress

Im creating a recomendation list but this code is not like what i wanted to.

```
<?php $recomendation= new WP_Query("post_type=movie&orderby=rand&showposts=5"); 

if($recomendation->have_posts()) : while($recomendation->have_posts()) : $recomendation->the_post();

 ?>
```

and i want to change orderby random to genre with option list
and auto refreshing the result after selecting the option.

Here is code that showed line of genres

```
<?php
            $taxonomy = 'genre';
            $tax_terms = get_terms($taxonomy,'number=15');
        ?>
        <ul>
        <?php
            foreach ($tax_terms as $tax_term){
            echo '<li>' . '<a href="' . esc_attr(get_term_link($tax_term, $taxonomy)) . '" title="' . sprintf( __( "genre %s" ), $tax_term->name ) . '" ' . '>' . $tax_term->name.'</a></li>';
        }
    ?>
        </ul>
```

> eg: [name movie genre action], [name movie genre horror], [name movie
>   genre drama], [name movie genre other]

(the result in default genre is all showed up).

after selecting option action

> eg: [name movie genre action]

(movie with action genre is only that showed up).

thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if I got this your question right but I will try. First of all, use get_posts instead of wp_query since the object never leaves the function. Do something like this:

```
$args = array(
  'posts_per_page' => 15,
  'post_type' => 'movie'
);

if(isset($_GET['genre_id'])):
  $args['tax_query'] => array(
    array(
      'taxonomy' => 'genre',
      'field' => 'id',
      'terms' => $_GET['genre_id'] //is sanitized by default
    )
  )
endif;

$movies = get_posts($args);
```